# How I can save scans to user's photo library in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I already tried plenty of solutions, but they doesn't works at all

```
    extension ViewController: VNDocumentCameraViewControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    func documentCameraViewController(_ controller: VNDocumentCameraViewController, didFinish scan: VNDocumentCameraScan) {
        for pageNumber in 0..<scan.pageCount {
            let image = scan.imageOfPage(at: pageNumber)
            print(image)
            //save
            hasPhoto = true
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
            //UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
        }
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: **Add permission to your .plist**

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>DummyProject wants to access your photo library to save photo</string>
```

Change message as per your need.

Step 2: **Make sure your image is not nil.**

```
func saveImage(image: UIImage) {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}
```

Step 3: **In your method, check error:**

```
@objc func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error ?? "Error in Image saving")
        return
    }
}
```

Please comment if you have any questions. Happy to help!

Comment: I test this solution, and found this messages in console: 
2020-11-22 17:19:36.187757+0300 Scan[49839:8341363] Errors found! Invalidating cache...
2020-11-22 17:19:36.245745+0300 Scan[49839:8341164] [TraitCollection] Class CKBrowserSwitcherViewController overrides the -traitCollection getter, which is not supported. If you're trying to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.
2020-11-22 17:19:36.504492+0300 Scan[49839:8341363] fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
2020-11-22 17:19:36.504832+0300 Scan[49839:8341363] Errors found! Invalidating cache...

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your code and check if the image exists.

Comment: Hello, I already put breakpoint in code, here messages from console:  2020-11-26 09:46:59.352185+0300 Scan[61926:10101501] [TraitCollection] Class CKBrowserSwitcherViewController overrides the -traitCollection getter, which is not supported. If you're trying to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.
2020-11-26 09:47:01.507988+0300 Scan[61926:10101947] Metal API Validation Enabled
2020-11-26 09:47:08.378448+0300 Scan[61926:10101940] [ServicesDaemonManager] interruptionHandler is called. -[FontServicesDaemonManager connection]_block_invoke

Answer (score 0):

for pageNumber in 0..<scan.pageCount {
let image = scan.imageOfPage(at: pageNumber)
print(image)
//save
hasPhoto = true

```
        UIImage* im = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: image.CGImage]; // make image from CGRef
        
        NSData* imdata =  UIImagePNGRepresentation ( im ); // get PNG representation
        UIImage* im2 = [UIImage imageWithData:imdata]; // wrap UIImage around PNG representation
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(im2, nil, nil, nil); // save to photo album
    }
```

Comment: hello, while I was testing this I found this error: '*' is not postfix unary operator